# Display items WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I need to display a cards game board. My BoardViewModelM exposes an IEnumerable where the CardViewModel has the information where the card should be drawn on the board.
I would like the baord to:

- Use all available size to draw the cards (scaling the location and size data provided by the cards, keeping proportions)
- Support zooming (including gestures zooming)

I was considering:

- create a custom ItemsControl (how?) and create a custom panel.
- Iterate on the collection and dynamically create a control for each one to place on a canvas (seems a bit crude)

What should be my course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use binding to display your card collection - one option is to use an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as the `ItemsPanel`, and set the `ItemContainerStyle` to position each card. Something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="{Binding CardImage}" Width="{Binding CardWidth}" Height="{Binding CardHeight}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CardX}" />
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CardY}" />                    
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did just that, only to apply re-sizing I created a custom Panel deriving from Canvas. Is it possible to instruct the canvas to auto-resizes content so that it displays all it's content using the space allocated for it?